Pygame screen not updating
I am trying to create an algorithm for towers of hanoi. It works well on nested lists. Now I want to visualize what is going on in pygame. Therefore I create a screen with three yellow rectangles as the towers and then a bunch of randomly colored rectangles as disks on top of it.
# import pygame package
import pygame
import numpy as np

# the towers, will become a list of tuples (position, width, color)
filledTowers = [[], [], []]

# game variables (variables to play around with)
NUMBEROFTOWERS = len(filledTowers)
NUMBEROFDISKS = 3
STARTTOWER = 0
ENDTOWER = 2

# color variables
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# tower variables
TOWERWIDTH = 50
TOWERY = 90
TOWERHEIGHT = 1000
towerXPos = [200, 725, 1250]

# disk variables
MAXDISKWIDTH = 400
DISKWIDTHDIFF = 40
DISKHEIGHT = 40
MAXDISKY = 900
moveCounter = 0


# function for filling the towers for the first time
def fill_towers(n, filledTowers):
    for i in range(n):
        color = list(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3))
        width = MAXDISKWIDTH - DISKWIDTHDIFF * i
        diskX = 200 - width / 2 + 25
        diskY = MAXDISKY - DISKHEIGHT * i
        filledTowers[0].append(
            {
                "color": color,
                "x": diskX,
                "y": diskY,
                "width": width,
                "height": DISKHEIGHT,
            }
        )
    print(filledTowers)
    return filledTowers


# filling the towers for the first time (number of disks, towers)
fill_towers(NUMBEROFDISKS, filledTowers)


def draw_stuff(towers, moveCounter, screen):

    # Fill the background with black
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # draw the towers
    for tower in range(NUMBEROFTOWERS):
        pygame.draw.rect(
            screen, YELLOW, (towerXPos[tower], TOWERY, TOWERWIDTH, TOWERHEIGHT)
        )

    # draw the disks
    for sublist in towers:
        for disk in sublist:
            color, x, y, width, height = disk.values()
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x, y, width, height))

    # draw the move counter
    text_surface = my_font.render(
        "moveCounter = " + str(moveCounter), False, (255, 255, 255)
    )
    moveCounter += 1
    screen.blit(text_surface, (0, 0))


# hanoi helper function for recursion
def hanoi_helper(start, end, towers, screen, moveCounter):
    if not towers[start]:
        return
    # print(towers)
    draw_stuff(towers, moveCounter, screen)
    disk = towers[start].pop()
    towers[end].append(disk)


# recursive hanoi solver function
def solve_hanoi(n, start, end, towers, screen, moveCounter):
    if n == 1:
        hanoi_helper(start, end, towers, screen, moveCounter)
    else:
        other = 3 - (start + end)
        solve_hanoi(n - 1, start, other, towers, screen, moveCounter)
        hanoi_helper(start, end, towers, screen, moveCounter)
        solve_hanoi(n - 1, other, end, towers, screen, moveCounter)


# initializing imported module
pygame.init()

# initializing the counter
pygame.font.init()
my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)

moveCounter = 0


# displaying a window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1500, 1000))

# Setting name for window
pygame.display.set_caption("Hanoi")

# creating a bool value which checks
# if game is running
running = True

# Game loop
while running:

    # Did the user click the window close button?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        else:
            running = True

    # draw the objects
    solve_hanoi(NUMBEROFDISKS, STARTTOWER, ENDTOWER, filledTowers, screen, moveCounter)

    # wait for 100 ms, so the algorithm works visibly slow
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    # Flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

# Done! Time to quit.
pygame.quit()



The code as it is can give me a screen with the amount of towers and disks I specified. The method solve_hanoi can solve the hanoi problem.
Sadly, I cannot get my screen to update and I could not find a solution for it with googling, looking at other stack overflow posts and ChatGPT and Gemini.
Do you have an idea, what I could try? (And how I should improve my StackOverflow post for the next time, I am still a newbie :)
I now moved the display.flip() out of the draw function like geometrian suggested.

Re improving your post: there's the obligatory guide. Personally, I feel like the code example should have been simpler and more debugging effort done, but I get it; screwing up the event loop is a common mistake that won't necessarily happen until you've written a larger program.

The problem with your code is essentially that you're mixing up the operations.  The usual way any graphical application works (even event-driven ones, internally) is:
#Frame loop
while running:
    #Handle events
    for event in pygame.events.get(): #...

    #Update any state that you need for the next frame
    update_stuff()

    #Draw everything
    draw_stuff()

    #Flip the back buffer to present the frame onto the screen
    pygame.display.flip()

In your code, the solve_hanoi(⋯) function does a bunch of stuff, including rendering, pygame.display.flip()ing, and pausing 100 ms to I guess slow down the rate the sequence displays.
The proximate problem is that this does not fit the main loop pattern given above.  The specific problem is you don't check for events.  What probably happens when you run this is it shows the screen, maybe updates it a few times, and then locks up.  It locks up because, without checking the events, they pile up.  Since actually compositing the window requires events to be handled, the window can't update anymore.
Just to be clear, the solution is to refactor your code so that it works like the pattern.  Don't do stuff like try to add event checking in internal functions or whatever.  For a program such as this, there should be exactly one call to pygame.events.get() and exactly one call to pygame.display.flip(), and they should each be called at least once a second (probably more like 60 times a second).

Thank your for the help, I will implement it. I thought I did not have any events, as there is no input on my side except from starting the algorithm. Why do I have to handle events still?

@ScamLikely you should at least handle a pygame.QUIT event so that your program can exit cleanly. You need to handle events so your desktop window manager/OS knows your program hasn't frozen. You could get away with using  pygame.event.pump(), as you're not otherwise handling events. However if you want to control the timing, you could use a timer event.

My game loop runs fine, this is not the problem. I found my problems:

While I pop and append the list objects correctly in my hanoi_helper, I do not change the x and y values. Therefore, they are drawn at the same position every time, regardless of their position in the array.
My function is recursive, thus I do not have control over the times it is called and I will only draw every few moves.

I fixed both by implementing the function iteratively. Thank you for your time, guys, I appreciate it! Here is my solution:
# import pygame package
import pygame
import numpy as np


# screen variables
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1000

# game variables (variables to play around with)
NUMBER_OF_DISKS = 7
# start tower and end tower only take values between 0 and 2
START_TOWER = 0
END_TOWER = 1

# color variables
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
NEON_GREEN = (57, 255, 20)
NEON_RED = (255, 36, 0)

# the towers, will become a list of tuples (position, width, color)
filledTowers = [[], [], []]

# tower variables
NUMBER_OF_TOWERS = len(filledTowers)
TOWER_WIDTH = 50
TOWER_Y = 90
TOWER_HEIGHT = 1000
towerXPos = [200, 725, 1250]

# disk variables
MAX_DISK_WIDTH = 400
DISK_WIDTH_DIFF = 40
DISK_HEIGHT = 40
MAX_DISK_Y = 900


class Counter:
    """a class to store the move counter"""

    _moveCounter = 0

    # increment the move counter
    def increment(self):
        self._moveCounter += 1


# function for filling the towers for the first time
def fill_towers(n, filledTowers):
    for i in range(n):
        color = list(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3))
        width = MAX_DISK_WIDTH - DISK_WIDTH_DIFF * i
        diskX = 200 - width / 2 + 25
        diskY = MAX_DISK_Y - DISK_HEIGHT * i
        filledTowers[0].append(
            {
                "color": color,
                "x": diskX,
                "y": diskY,
                "towerWidth": width,
                "height": DISK_HEIGHT,
            }
        )
    # print(filledTowers)
    return filledTowers


# filling the towers for the first time (number of disks, towers)
fill_towers(NUMBER_OF_DISKS, filledTowers)


def draw_stuff(towers, screen, count, my_font):

    # Fill the background with black
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # draw the towers
    for tower in range(NUMBER_OF_TOWERS):
        pygame.draw.rect(
            screen, YELLOW, (towerXPos[tower], TOWER_Y, TOWER_WIDTH, TOWER_HEIGHT)
        )

    # draw the disks
    for tower in towers:
        for disk in tower:
            color, x, y, width, height = disk.values()
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x, y, width, height))

    # draw the move counter
    text_surface = my_font.render(
        "moveCounter = " + str(count._moveCounter), False, (255, 255, 255)
    )
    screen.blit(text_surface, (0, 0))


# lay a text over the finished towers
def draw_end_screen(screen, count, my_font):

    # draw the end screen message
    end_message = f"Towers of Hanoi finished in {count._moveCounter} moves"
    text_surface = my_font.render(end_message, False, (NEON_RED))
    screen.blit(
        text_surface,
        (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2 - text_surface.get_width() // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2),
    )


def hanoi_move(start, end, towers):
    disk = towers[start].pop()
    disk["x"] = towerXPos[end] - disk["towerWidth"] / 2 + 25
    disk["y"] = MAX_DISK_Y - DISK_HEIGHT * len(towers[end])
    towers[end].append(disk)


def solve_hanoi_iterative(n, start, end, towers, count):
    stack = [(n, start, end)]
    while stack:
        n, start, end = stack.pop()
        if n == 1:
            hanoi_move(start, end, towers)
            count.increment()
            yield
        else:
            other = 3 - (start + end)
            stack.append((n - 1, other, end))
            stack.append((1, start, end))
            stack.append((n - 1, start, other))


# initializing imported module
pygame.init()

# initializing the counter
pygame.font.init()
my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)
count = Counter()


# displaying a window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# Setting name for window
pygame.display.set_caption("Hanoi solver")

# creating a bool value which checks
# if game is running
running = True

# create a generator for drawing the objects
hanoi_generator = solve_hanoi_iterative(
    NUMBER_OF_DISKS, START_TOWER, END_TOWER, filledTowers, count
)

# flag to check if the algorithm is finished
algorithm_finished = False

# Game loop
while running:

    # Did the user click the window close button?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    # draw the objects
    if not algorithm_finished:
        draw_stuff(filledTowers, screen, count, my_font)

        # try to execute the next move in the generator, if the algorithm is finished, draw the end screen
        try:
            next(hanoi_generator)
        except StopIteration:
            algorithm_finished = True

    else:
        draw_end_screen(screen, count, my_font)

    # flip the display and delay the moves
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(300)


# Done! Time to quit.
pygame.quit()

